# Easiest DAX function to add a Last 7 Day marker column to a Calendar table

Tags: dax

I have a Calendar table and would like to add a calculated column "Is Last 7 Days" - it should be either 1 or 0 - so if DayMarker is within the last 7 days it shows 1 ortherwise 0.

I have this DAX expression which seems over-complicated - what is the easy way?

```
Last 7 Days = 
IF(
    'Calendar'[DayMarker] >=
        MAXX(
            ALL('Calendar')
            , DATEADD('Calendar'[DayMarker],-7,DAY) 
            )
    ,1
    ,0
)
```

Comment: Last 7 days relative to today or some other anchor point?

Comment: hi Alex - relative to the Maximum DayMarker in the calendar table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Last 7 Days = IF(MAX('Calendar'[DayMarker]) - 'Calendar'[DayMarker] < 7, 1, 0)
```

If you prefer, you can use `DATEDIFF` instead of subtraction:

```
Last7Days = IF(DATEDIFF('Calendar'[DayMarker], MAX('Calendar'[DayMarker]), DAY) < 7, 1, 0)
```

Comment: thank you - i seem to have a natural tendency to over-complicate things (and not just code)

Comment: hello alexis do you have any idea what is happening in this question - it is driving me insane: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340963/filtered-measure-seemingly-not-working. I cannot understand why the `SELECTEDVALUE` result is not being used in the `CALCULATE`