# Filtered Measure seemingly not working

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this data:

[image]

Then I have this donut of fruit:

[image]

I have this measure to pick-up which fruit has been selected in the above donut:

```
Selected Fruit = SELECTEDVALUE( Fruit[Fruit] )
```

It seems to work fine e.g. if I add this measure to a card and click Pear:

[image]

Now comes the problem - I have a bar chart **which has to have interactions turned off** but still needs to be filtered by what has been selected in the donut - so I created this measure:

```
Value Filtered = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Fruit[Value])
    ,FILTER(
        Fruit
        ,Fruit[Fruit] = [Selected Fruit]
    )
)
```

But now when I click Pear it changes the text in the card but has no impact on the chart - what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Please note that if I change the DAX to the following then it works:

```
Value Filtered = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fruit[Value])
        ,FILTER(
            Fruit
            ,Fruit[Fruit] = “Pear”
        )
    )
```

---

EDIT

@RADO suggested the following two approaches but neither works for me:

```
Value Filtered = 
VAR Selected_Fruit = [Selected Fruit]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Fruit[Value])
        ,FILTER(
            Fruit
            ,Fruit[Fruit] = Selected_Fruit
        )
    )


Value Filtered = 
VAR Selected_Fruit = [Selected Fruit]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
       SUM(Fruit[Value]),
       Fruit[Fruit] = Selected_Fruit
    )
```

I do agree that the problem must be something to do with re-calculation of the context within the calculation. I don't understand why this approach using a variable is not working for me!

Comment: Can you elaborate why you can't have the interactions for the donut chart to the bar chart turned on, if this is exactly what you're trying to do after all?

Comment: In the real report the donut and the bar chart are both filtered also by Date BUT different date ranges - if the user  interacts with the donut I only want the Fruit context to get pushed onto the bar chart and not the Date context

Comment: @RADO but in reality the bar chart has a date filter context, as does the donut, but they are different: the donut is past 30 days and the bar chart is 90 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to filter and not filter at the same time. You can't have it both ways. When you turn off interaction, the bar chart cannot respond to anything that happens in the donut chart since you've removed it from the filter context. It doesn't matter what you write in your measure, you can't access selections while simultaneously disabling interaction.

That said, I'm sure your original problem can be solved. I'd suggest cooking up a minimal example with the date element included and posting a question that explains that question more fully.